# Size of Variables in x86

Tags: assembly, disassembly

Where does the size of the variables defined in the C files appear in the assembly equivalent of the code after the compilation?

Imagine your first code is:

```
char buffer[2];
char a[3];
```

and your next code is:

```
char buffer[3];
char a[2];
```

where "buffer" and "a" are local variables of a function.

In both cases, the `esp` is reduced by the same number of bytes when you enter the function, but is there any way to distinguish the border if you do not have access to the source code and you are just disassembling the binary?

I am wondering if there is a segment in the binary that keeps track of the size of variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, the only way to tell in this circumstance is to look at how the stack is being used.

Once code is compiled to assembly, type information isn't really preserved, the only thing that can be inferred is the type of assembly instructions being used(whether they operate on a bit, word, double word, ect)

IDA Pro has a disassemble to C feature that is usually mostly accurate, it doesn't reduce to working C most of the time but is pretty powerful in fast analysis of ASM. One thing it does is find out the size of arrays, however a lot of the time it will only type them as byte(or char) arrays and you might have to analyze the code to see how its being used exactly.

Comment: There no way to determine the border, but there is software out there that explicitly adds border markers for the purposes of overflow detection. Visual Studio for example has this option IIRC and will break the debugger if it detects the "guard bytes" have been overwritten.

Comment: Isn't this sort of thing only present when code is compiled with debug mode? A lot of things get tossed when code gets compiled for "release" for the sake of efficient CPU and memory use.

Comment: I assumed that stack canaries are disabled when the source was compiled, and I am just playing with the binary.

Comment: Yes, its a debug-only feature.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if there is a segment in the binary that keeps track of the size of variables.

No, there isn't.

At most you can find the relative offsets of the variables, together with the total stack allocated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's put in a separate file (or even more commonly: nowhere), but debug information such as this *may* be kept in the binary. You can't rely on that, obviously, but if you have control over the production of the binary you can arrange for the information to be there.

Comment: In the application I am considering, I have no control over how the source code is compiled and there is no debug info available, only the reloc info.

Comment: @Afshin then the data isn't anywhere. You can only try to infer it from how it is used.